# why the bracket can't be omitted in int.to_bytes?

Tags: python

```
>>> x=3
>>> x.to_bytes(2,"big")
b'\x00\x03'
>>> 3.to_bytes(2,"big")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    3.to_bytes(2,"big")
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> (3).to_bytes(2,"big")
b'\x00\x03'
```

Why i can't omit the bracket `3.to_bytes(2,"big")`?This bracket  has what function here?

Comment: It looks like for the very reason stackoverflow has handled its highlighting the way it has. It might be that python sees a number and a period and starts to read in a float, whereas in brackets in knows it's looking for an integer and to correspond that to to_bytes using the period. Just a guess though.

Comment: That's (essentially) correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the brackets, Python is attempting to parse `3.to_bytes` as a floating point number; that is, it's trying to make `3.<something>` and there's a syntax failure when you try to access `to_bytes` without the dot.

If you add an extra dot, it finishes the parsing of the float and attempts to access the method, which doesn't exist:

```
>>> 3..to_bytes(2, "big")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'to_bytes'
```

If you have it in the brackets it passes because it doesn't try to make the floating point number. You can also run it with a space to get around this:

```
>>> 3 .to_bytes(2, "big")
b'\x00\x03'
>>> 3.to_bytes(2, "big")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    3.to_bytes(2, "big")
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When you store the `int` in a variable, Python doesn't attempt to parse it as a `float`, which is why you don't see it that way as well when using `x.to_bytes()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `3.` by itself is a decimal (float type) number.  So `3.to_bytes` is parsed as `(3.)to_bytes` which is invalid.  So you need to say `(3).to_bytes` to give the dot the meaning you intended.

Comment: This answer could be improved by giving an example how to access a property of a numeric literal.