# Why is it a syntax error to invoke a method on a numeric literal in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

I can invoke methods on numbers only when I bind them to a name:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> a.bit_length()
3
```

I can invoke methods on string literals:

```
>>> 'Hello World'.lower()
'hello world'
```

But I cannot invoke methods on numeric literals:

```
>>> 5.bit_length()
```

This raises a `SyntaxError`. Is there a practical reason for that, or is it historic?

**Edit** Just found this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955703/accessing-a-python-int-literals-methods) that shows workarounds (that have already been suggested here as well). I guess this also answers the main question - with simple workarounds available, there probably wasn't enough benefit to making the grammar more complex (and harder to parse) to make this work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why the bracket can't be omitted in int.to\_bytes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875862/why-the-bracket-cant-be-omitted-in-int-to-bytes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The floating point numbers are parsed as per the following rules, [quoting from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating-point-literals),

```
floatnumber   ::=  pointfloat | exponentfloat
pointfloat    ::=  [intpart] fraction | intpart "."
exponentfloat ::=  (intpart | pointfloat) exponent
intpart       ::=  digit+
fraction      ::=  "." digit+
exponent      ::=  ("e" | "E") ["+" | "-"] digit+
```

When Python sees `5.`, it thinks that the grammar follows `[intpart] fraction | intpart "."` rule. So, it picks up the next character and finds that it doesn't match the `fraction` rule. That is why the syntax error is thrown.

You can get around that by

```
5 .bit_length()
```

Or enclosing that in brackets like this

```
(5).bit_length()
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually thefourtheye is slightly mistaken in that the reason for syntax error is not that the `fraction` rule is not matched.

The reason for the syntax error is that that this rule is used to parse it as a floating point:

```
pointfloat    ::=  [intpart] fraction | intpart "."
```

The number matches the second form, that has integer part followed by a `.` - `5.` is a valid literal for floating point, and the token stream produced by `5.bit_length` produces 2 tokens: `5.` (that is, float `5.0`)  and `bit_length`; a floating point literal followed by a name is syntax error in python.

It is actually possible to call a float method however, with 2 dots:

```
>>> 5.0.hex()
'0x1.4000000000000p+2'
>>> 5..hex()
'0x1.4000000000000p+2'
```

To call the `int` method, you need to separate the `5` from `.` to make them parsed as separate tokens.